# title selector not responding to font-size rule in css for Rmarkdown html report

Tags: css, yaml, r-markdown

The font size of my title, "Utilize Css" seems unresponsive to the `font-size` argument in my `css` style sheet saved in the same directory. I have experimented with all the other arguments in this `css` style sheet, and they all update the report as expected, but the font-size argument for the title selector has no impact on the title in the report.

I am using a `YAML` header like this

```
---
title: "Utilize Css"
author: "Me"
date: "2019-07-15"
output:
  html_document:
    css: style.css
---
```

And a style sheet like this

```
.title {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.author, .date {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

As you can see, all font sizes were set by the css style sheet except the title's font size.[image: screenshot]

How can I use a `css` style sheet to control the font size of the title in an `html` report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to us `h1.title` in your style.css file to control the title size.

```
h1.title {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.author, .date {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

Comment: This results in the margin warning "Element (h1.title) is overqualified, just use .title without element name." However, this does not prevent the css style sheet from working, and the html report does now look the way I want it to.

Comment: It seems a strange warning, as `.title` clearly doesn't have any effect as you describe. I don't get a warning on my system, running `R 3.6.0`, `rmarkdown 1.14` and `pandoc 2.7.1`. Glad it is working for you even with the warning though.